# How to get Client IP Address and Stored Procedure Update history?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using sample database in server (name EX: rr). In sample database i am having stored procedures and that can be accessed by employees. Now my question is some body modified one Stored Procedure (Ex: SP_EmpInsert). Now i would like to know the history of that stored procedure when it is modified and in which computer(IP Address of computer) it is modified.

**I referred this link**
[Get username and/or IP address responsible for a query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46009/get-username-and-or-ip-address-responsible-for-a-query)

Comment: What about users and privileges? Don't grant anything not required to anybody.

Comment: Tip of the day: SVN.

Comment: simply put, you can't. no way to get the ip address for a specific modification directly: you may be able to get to the ip if you can retrieve the session but you have to enable auditing BEFORE the modification is made. also it is quite odd to hunt for the modifier: usually people acting on the structure are few and 'friendly' (not willing to create issues...).

Comment: @Dineshalla For future add DDL trigger and log all DDL operations. Now is to late. Second store all script of your DB in version control like Git/SVN. Last prepare DEV/TEST/PROD environments, don't allow dev anonymously change PROD enviroment.

Comment: @Dineshalla make unique username for each developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fisrt we need to create Database**

```
CREATE DATABASE HistoryDB;
GO
```

**Need to create table to store logs**

```
USE HistoryDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_SPHistory
(
    EventDate    DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    EventType    NVARCHAR(64),
    EventDDL     NVARCHAR(MAX),
    EventXML     XML,
    DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255),
    SchemaName   NVARCHAR(255),
    ObjectName   NVARCHAR(255),
    HostName     VARCHAR(64),
    IPAddress    VARCHAR(32),
    ProgramName  NVARCHAR(255),
    LoginName    NVARCHAR(255)
);
```

**Need to insert stored procedures for which we need to create logs**

```
INSERT HistoryDB.dbo.tbl_SPHistory
(
    EventType,
    EventDDL,
    DatabaseName,
    SchemaName,
    ObjectName,
    LoginName
)
SELECT
    'CREATE_PROCEDURE',
    OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id]),
    DB_NAME(),
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
    OBJECT_NAME([object_id]),
    'my name'
FROM
    sys.procedures;
```

**Finally we need to create DDL Trigger**

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DDLTrigger_Sample
    ON DATABASE
    FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE
        @EventData XML = EVENTDATA();

    DECLARE 
        @ip VARCHAR(32) =
        (
            SELECT client_net_address
                FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
                WHERE session_id = @@SPID
        );

    INSERT HistoryDB.dbo.tbl_SPHistory
    (
        EventType,
        EventDDL,
        EventXML,
        DatabaseName,
        SchemaName,
        ObjectName,
        HostName,
        IPAddress,
        ProgramName,
        LoginName
    )
    SELECT
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]',   'NVARCHAR(100)'), 
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        @EventData,
        DB_NAME(),
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'), 
        @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'),
        HOST_NAME(),
        @ip,
        PROGRAM_NAME(),
        SUSER_SNAME();
END
GO
```

**Also Refer the link for detail explanation**
[SQL Server DDL Triggers to Track All Database Changes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/)